# Uncaught ReferenceError: goAndFind is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

i think i am doing everything fine but still i am getting this error. anybody please guide me through. i have two functions in my javascript file first is myfunction and second is goAndFind  but first is working fine on ng-change but both function doesnt work onclick on a button :

this is my javascript file

```js
/// <reference path="angular.min.js"/>
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDTTDn-oR0XadcSwllwUkukrw86eH2Ch0g",
    authDomain: "mvprecovery.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://mvprecovery.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "mvprecovery.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "119468568560"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var myapp = angular
                    .module("mymodule", ['firebase'])
                    .controller("mycontroller", function ($scope , $firebaseObject) {
                        
                        $scope.selectState;
                        $scope.findTreatment = findTreatment;
                        $scope.selectState = selectState;
                        $scope.selectedInsurance = selectedInsurance;

                        $scope.goAndFind = function writeUserData() {
                                        firebase.database().ref('tempdata/' + userId).set({
                                            insurance: $scope.selectedInsurance,
                                            state: $scope.selectState,
                                            treatment: $scope.findTreatment
                            });
                        };

                        $scope.myfunction = function () {
                            if ($scope.selectState == "Pennsylvania") {
                                $scope.insurance = [
                                                    { name: "Ford Mustang" },
                                                    { name: "Fiat 500" },
                                                    { name: "Volvo XC90" }
                                ];
                            } else if ($scope.selectState == "new-jersey") {
                                $scope.insurance = [
                                               { name: "lahore" },
                                               { name: "kamalia" },
                                               { name: "bingokml" }
                                ];
                            }  
                        };

});
```

and this is my button code that is clicked

```html
 <input type="button" class="btn-success" id="findTreatment" value="Find Treatment" ng-disabled="myform.$invalid && myform.insurancefield.$invalid" onclick="goAndFind()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-click instead of onclick since you're using angular.

```
<input type="button" class="btn-success" id="findTreatment" value="Find Treatment" ng-disabled="myform.$invalid && myform.insurancefield.$invalid" ng-click="goAndFind()" />
```

Also, consider giving your functions a clearer name (e.g., `setInsurance` instead of `myfunction`). That will help you later on.